# How are the definitions of Weil divisors with subsets and subscheme equivalent?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I've seen a Weil divisor be defined in two slightly similar ways and I'm not sure I understand why they are equivalent (assuming that indeed they are. They are as follows.

A Weil divisor on X is a finite linear combination with integral coefficients of:
1.irreducible closed subsets Z of X of codimension one
2.closed integral subscheme Y of codimension 1

Answer (score 2):

They are equivalent because of the following. Given any closed subset $Z\subseteq X$ of a scheme there is NOT a unique scheme structure on $Z$. But, there is a unique *minimal* scheme structure—the one coming from the reduced structure on $Z$. Explicitly, find an ideal sheaf $\mathcal{I}$ of $X$ which cuts out $Z$ and take the scheme structure on $Z$ given by $\mathcal{O}_Z/\sqrt{\mathcal{I}}$. This is called the *reduced structure* on $Z$

Your answer should be pretty clear once you recall that a scheme $Z$ is integral if and only if it's reduced and irreducible. So, to a closed irreducible subset $Z\subseteq X$ of comdimension $1$, there is a unique closed integral subscheme having $Z$ as its underlying space.